# Can I come to the UK if I marry a single mother

Tags: uk-citizens

Can I come to the UK if I marry a single mother who has British citizenship, although am not the father of her child?

Comment: Do you mean visit, or come to live in the UK? What is your citizenship? Note that many of the related visas are **very** expensive. If you plan to come live in the UK, then this question is more appropriate on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: As this question is now there is not enough information to answer it covering the different options. Please add your nationality, whether you want to visit or immigratie and as many details as you are happy to share. There is not enough information to move the question to Expatriates.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you would be eligible to apply as a parent. You need to have sole or shared parental responsibility for your child. If you share parental responsibility, the child’s other parent must not be your partner.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/parent

You could apply as a [partner or spouse](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse) if you meet the eligibility requirements.